# GET method causes an error

Tags: php, get, ashx

sorry for the title but I'm not reaaly sure how to call this.

I am registered to a ssm service which enables sending automatic sms with a php script. 
the script basically builds an xml string with all of the sms parameters (sendername, ..).

then it uses this to send it :

```
$sms_host = "api.inforu.co.il"; // Application server's URL;  
    $sms_port = 80; // Application server's PORT; 

    ////.... generating query 
    $sms_path = "/SendMessageXml.ashx"; // Application server's PATH; 
    $fp = fsockopen($sms_host, $sms_port, $errno, $errstr, 30); // Opens a socket to the Application server
    if (!$fp){ // Verifies that the socket has been opened and sending the message; 
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n"; 
        echo "no error";
    } else  {
        $out = "GET $sms_path?$query HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: $sms_host\r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

        fwrite($fp, $out);
        while (!feof($fp)){ 
            echo fgets($fp, 128); 
        } 
        fclose($fp);
```

the query is fine if I paste this

```
$url = "http://api.inforu.co.il/SendMessageXml.ashx?" . $query;
```

directly in the browser, then the sms gets send.

so the problem is that I'm getting an error

Server Error in '/' Application.

```
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /SendMessageXml.ashx
```

Comment: Instead of manually crafting your HTTP request, just use [`file_get_contents()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), assuming `allow_url_fopen` is enabled. `$retval = file_get_contents("http://api.inforu.co.il/SendMessageXml.ashx?" . $query);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to [urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode) your `$query`, if you paste it to browser, the browser will encode it for you, but when you are dealing with a socket, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: i did urlencode it - $query = 'InforuXML=' . urlencode('<Inforu><User><Username>'. 
 $sms_user.'</Username><Password>'. 
 $sms_password.'</Password></User><Content Type="sms"><Message>'). 
 $message_text.urlencode('</Message></Content><Recipients><PhoneNumber>'. 
 $recepients.'</PhoneNumber></Recipients><Settings>><SenderName>'. 
 $sms_sender_name.'</SenderName><SenderNumber>'. 
 $sms_sender_num.'</SenderNumber><CustomerParameter>'. 
 $customer_parameter.'</CustomerParameter></Settings></Inforu>');